# Eyelids with Shape Keys

Tags: animation, shape-keys

I seem to be having difficulty with the eyelids of my model using Shape Keys. I'm trying to get the top and bottom eyelids to close, but due to the design of the character and their eye sockets, which are slanted, I can't seem to get it right. Any suggestions?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you select the last lid edge loop, activate the *Proportional Editing* (*Connected* option), scale on the Z axis, rotate a bit, it looks ok to me,  no? You have to be a bit skilful with the *Proportional Editing* influence radius.

[image]

Comment: Well, that was a lot easier than I thought lol. Thanks, that did the job nicely. :D